# Keras: Simple network to generate images doesn't learn anything

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to build my first Keras model, but it isn't learning anything. I think this problem is quite specific to me (that is to say, it's because I'm doing something wrong, not a general question), so let me know if there's a better place to post it.

**The short version:**
I'm trying to train a network to take as input a list (that represents an image) and generate another list/array, that can also be displayed as an image. However, the loss doesn't change during training, and  every input gives the exact same output. See my code below.

**Context**

- I've generated 2000 images of 'tumors' like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U48iU.png)
- For each image, I've simulated the results of a PET-scan of the tumor, which are represented by an array that can be shown as an image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkGAf.png). Each point (x,y) tells the number of times sensor x and sensor y have responded at the same time (which is important because of physics). For this reason, every image is actually symmetrical, so to reduce the amount of data I'm just using a nested list that contains all the information (format: [[a],[b,c],[d,e,f],...], where a is the number of events at sensorpair 0-0, b is sensorpair 1-0, c 1-1 etc.)

**Goal**

I want to train a network that can go from the sensor-results back to the tumor-image. Since this is my first network, I wanted to make it simple for myself and train a dense network. I know this isn't ideal, but this was really just a test to get myself a baseline to beat - but it appears I'm doing something wrong already

So - does anyone know what is wrong in my code? What layer should I use as my output layer, and with what activation? What would be a reasonable loss function?

**The preprocessing code (jupyter notebook and sample images [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iEiqOXGtu3lMtYXJkrXVuhKBZ6pRFYBt)):**

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

def import_input(nr):
    with open(Path('Sensor_half_matrixes_small/' + str(nr) + '.txt'), 'rb') as file:
        data = pickle.load(file)
        data = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist] #the file is in a format that I want to flatten
        return data

def import_output(nr):
    im = Image.open(Path('Math_tumor_images/' + str(nr) + '.png'))
    a = np.array(im)
    im.close()
    a = a[:,:,0] #take only one color channel (they're all the same since it's grayscale)
    a = np.full(a.shape, 255) - a #invert it so white=0, black=255. not sure this does anything, but it makes more sense to me
    #downsample to 70*70. The original images are 420*420, but that seemed unnecessary
    a = a[:, ::6] + a[:, 1::6] + a[:, 2::6] + a[:, 3::6] + a[:, 4::6] + a[:, 5::6]
    a = a[::6, :] + a[1::6, :] + a[2::6, :] + a[3::6, :] + a[4::6, :] + a[5::6, :]
    a = a.flatten() #flatten
    a = a.tolist()
    return(a)

input_list = []
output_list = []
for filenr in range(0,2000): #if you want to test it, I've only uploaded 21 images of each kind
    input = import_input(filenr)
    input_list.append(input)
    output = import_output(filenr)
    output_list.append(output)

input_tensor_train = np.array(input_list[:1400])
output_tensor_train = np.array(output_list[:1400])
input_tensor_test = np.array(input_list[1400:])
output_tensor_test = np.array(output_list[1400:])
```

**The actual network**
I assume this is where the problem really is.

```
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(2080, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (2080,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(2080,activation = 'relu'))
network.add(layers.Dense(4900, activation = 'sigmoid')) #I'm especially unsure about this layer. Is it even possible to 'upsample' from 2080 to 4900?

network.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mse') #Is there a better loss function? I guess I'm loosing some spatial information here...

history = network.fit(input_tensor_train, output_tensor_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

**The result**
During the fit, the loss stays the same with small variations, both for validation and for the normal training data.
When I try to predict using `network.predict(input_tensor_test)`, I get some very similar arrays back for every input, and when I try to display them as images, they are indistinguishable - it actually seems like a valid answer ([it's vaguely circle-esque](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwFlH.png)), but it shouldn't be the same for every input.

Comment: Do you have any real data? And it's unclear what you are trying to achieve with a bunch of dense layers, try GANs if you want to generate images.

Comment: @Bharath All the data is simulated, it's more a proof of concept than anything else (it's for a high-school paper). I have thought about a GAN, but I don't really have two networks to pit against each other. This is about taking some specific data (the sensor events) and using it to figure out where the tumor was, not trying to generate images that look like data (which is what my understanding of GANs is).